# TensorFlow Poisson error

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am trying to assume that my y variable has a Poisson distribution and I am using TensorFlow to do so. The model I have is as follows:

```
def my_dist_Poisson(params):
    return tfd.Poisson(rate=1.0)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
  tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(my_dist_Poisson),
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.05), loss=NLL)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, verbose=True)
```

The variable I am trying to predict is the 'cnt' variable in the following dataset (for regression): https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/bike+sharing+dataset

However, I get the following error and don't seem to know why this shows up.

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense_24/kernel:0', 'dense_24/bias:0'].
```